# Uploading spatial data (.shp) to PostGIS db through a .NET Core app

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, postgis, spatial

I'm a beginner and I'm currently working on a pet project where a user could upload a shapefile (.shp) to a PostGIS database and then show the uploaded point, line or polygon on a interactive map.

I figured out the showing on map part but I'm clueless what my pipeline for user uploading the .shp files should look like. I added the test files using shp2pgsql.
My project is in .NET core and I would be grateful for some code examples with pipeline suggestions.

Bonus question: is there a way to check the coordinate system of the .shp being uploaded?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/)

```
            Shapefile shpfile =
                Shapefile.OpenFile(shpFilePath);
            foreach (var feature in shpfile.Features)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(feature.Geometry);
            }
```

PS. Dependencies for code above are: DotSpatial.Data, DotSpatial.GeoAPI, DotSpatial.NetTopologySuite, System.Text.Encoding.CodePages